# How to add an existing contact to an existing group 

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, abaddressbook

How can I add `ABPerson` to `ABGroups` in MonoTouch?

i use `ABGroup.Add()` following exception fires

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: cfErrorHandle must not be null.
>   Parameter name: cfErrorHandle

I select already exist ABPerson using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.

```
ABAddressBook adBook = new ABAddressBook();
```

//ABPeoplePickerNavigationController SelectPerson event
void HandleAbPeoplePickerSelectPerson (object sender, ABPeoplePickerSelectPersonEventArgs e)
{

```
if(_isNew )
{

    CreateGroup (txtNewGroup .Text);

    AddPersontoGroup(txtNewGroup .Text, e.Person);


}

if(!e.Continue )
    this.NavigationController .DismissModalViewControllerAnimated (true);
```

}

public void AddPersontoGroup(string strGroupName,ABPerson person )
{
    ABGroup[] allGroups = adBook.GetGroups();

```
for (int rowIndex=0; rowIndex<allGroups.Length ;rowIndex++)
{
    ABGroup abGroup=allGroups [rowIndex];

    if(abGroup.Name ==strGroupName)
    {
        abGroup.Add(person);
        adBook.Save ();
        break;
    }
}
```

}

public void CreateGroup(string strGroupName)
{

`ABGroup grp = new ABGroup ();
grp.Name = strGroupName;
adBook.Add(grp);
adBook.Save ();`

}

Thanks

Ramesh K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address book can be peculiar. E.g. Adding a `ABPerson` to a `ABGroup` is valid ony if the `ABPerson` is part of the `ABAddressBook` (i.e. adding it to a group does not, automagically, does that).

This code, basically what you're doing with **one extra line**, will work.

```
        ABAddressBook adBook = new ABAddressBook ();
        ABGroup grp = new ABGroup ();
        grp.Name = "Test";
        adBook.Add (grp);
        adBook.Save (); 

        ABPerson p = new ABPerson ();
        adBook.Add (p);

        grp.Add (p);
        adBook.Save ();
```

but if you remove the line adding the `ABPerson` to the `ABAddressBook` you'll get the same error that you already experience.

```
        adBook.Add (p);
```